# Check if in url id & title exists and match in database, else redirect

Tags: php, redirect, googlebot

Im kinda confused about this matter.
If u visit on my website the page

> /news/1/this-is-right

or

> /news/1/this-is-not-right

You will still get the same webpage because the script uses the ID var to get the content, now I was wondering that if somone when visiting my website would change the title of the news post, would google index that too?

Any ideas on how I can check if the ID does match the TITLE, and if not redirect them to the right page?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the title into a slug and store it into the database and then you can retrieve your SQL results the same as using your numeric ID, except you use the `slug` column.